# `non-object-ness` of `nil` in ruby

Tags: ruby

From one of the online resource of Ruby I found the below statement:

> The special object nil is, indeed, an object (it’s the only instance of a class called
>   NilClass). But in practice, it’s also a kind of non-object. The boolean value of nil is
>   false, but that’s just the start of its non-object-ness.

While `nil` responds to method calls as below,like other objects,what `non-objectness` author tried to say :

```
nil.to_s #=> ""
nil.to_i #=> 0
nil.object_id #=> 4
nil.inspect #=> "nil"
```

Can anyone help me here to understand the philosophy - `non-object-ness` of `nil` ?

Comment: Do you want us to read the rest of the book for you?

Comment: There 3 more pages in the book you cite that discuss the subject of the non-object-ness. Aren't the explanations there good for you? Maybe more precise question will be useful?

Comment: Okay so which book you are talking about, where 3 pages are used to describe this thing.please give me the name,I will read it out.I don't have with me that book. If I do, then i will read those pages before posting. So the book name if handy with you please share. My confusion with `nil`. `nil` is a object - why then again it has been said that `non-object-ness`. this made me confused.

Comment: This is the book: http://www.scribd.com/doc/119420527/Manning-Ruby-for-Rails. You have exact extract from it. Page 250.

Comment: It sounds like a stupid philosophy, so I won't try to explain it. `nil` is an object. It's also both a singleton and an immediate, properties it shares with `true` and `false`; Symbols and Fixnums are also immediates.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev FYI i am not following `ROR` right now. I am only studying the `Ruby`. Thus you may think I copied from there,but it is not true.

Answer (score 0):

`nil` is equivalent with `null` in other languages. Usually, `null` should not treated as a sane value.

However - as you may noticed -  the syntax of Ruby language does everything over the method calls on objects, a lot more things than Python. Determining a sanity of values is a part of it.

Consider the following example

```
def foobar(arg)
  if arg < 1
    return nil
  else
    return "Oh, hi!"
  end
end

res = foobar(rand(2))
puts res unless res.nil?
```

As you see, in the last line I check the nil-ness of the result with calling a `nil?` method. This is a most effective way to do it, because comparation operators can be overloaded and can do a very different things. The `nil?` returns with `true` only if the value can be treated as `nil` (usually, if the value is nil - but `nil?` method is overridable too, even if it is highly discouraged. Developers usually are not override this method).

Another useful property of `nil` it is has a `to_s` method, so you can `x = "#{nil}` and it results an empty string.

If `nil` weren't be an object, you cannot call `nil?` or other useful functions on that, but you can faced with a NullPointerException like in Java or a segmentation fault like in C/C++. And usually it is pointless.